# How to extract all properties (Paper Size, Format, Producer) of a PDF using java program

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, pdf-reader

I am able to extract PDF properties using java code as below:
But i am confused how to get [Format like "PDF1.3" and page Size like"A4, Portrait (210 × 297 mm)"] properties using java code.

```
System.out.println(file.getName());
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file.toString());
HashMap<String, String> info = reader.getInfo(); 
char info1=reader.getPdfVersion();
byte[] b1 = reader.getMetadata();
System.out.println(info);
System.out.println(info1);
```

I have tried PDFbox API also, but i cant find the method for the same,
Is it possible to fetch the following properties using java (i am using ubuntu)

ScreenShot of what i wanted to extract:

[image: ScreenShot of what i wanted to extract]

Comment: try pdf box. it'll help you..[here is link](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)
there are methods to calculate paper size

Comment: thanks, i got few properties but i am unable to find pdf verison and page Size

Comment: *page size* is a property of each individual page, not of the document as a whole. Only if by chance all document pages have the same size, it would make sense to call that size a document property.

Comment: check below answer..I added some sample code

Comment: Thanks a lot, as i am intermediate in java language, can you please share any snippet which takes a pdf and read the properties (Paper Size). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added sample code which can give all information, I just displayed basic properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can get document information using `PDDocument` class in `PDFBox api`. `PDDocumentInformation` is used to retrieve author, version, created date, updated date, etc features.

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath));
PDDocumentInformation info = doc.getDocumentInformation();
String author = info.getAuthor();
int pages = doc.getNumberOfPages();
// String creator  = info.getCreator();
Calendar calendar = info.getCreationDate();
System.out.println("Author : " + author);
System.out.println("Created : " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa").format(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
System.out.println("Total Pages : " + pages);
if(pages > 0) {
    float width = doc.getPage(0).getMediaBox().getWidth();
    float height = doc.getPage(0).getMediaBox().getHeight();
    System.out.println("Page 0 size : " + width + " * " + height);
} else {
    System.err.println("No pages.");
}
```

### **Edit**

Here is link to [Get Page Format](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.12/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#getPageFormat(int)).

Here is link to [Get Page information](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#getDocumentInformation()) and [Author](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocumentInformation.html#getAuthor()).

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Using a `PDFTextStripper` is overkill.Why parsing the whole content stream of a page to get the page object if you can simply get it without. And the links you added in your edit are for very different versions of PDFBox, 1.8.12 for "Get Page Format" and 2.0.2 for "Get Page information". These versions do not really mix well...

Comment: Thanks a lot, just one last thread into this post , is it possible to change the property paper size = US Letter into A4 through java, if yes how to do it. Thanks in advance i really appreciated the help.

Comment: you've to find it, i have not done this before..but there must be something to achieve this..